# Retrieve explain output from Teradata using Python

Tags: python, teradata, explain

Is there any possibility to retrieve explain output in Teradata with python?

Eg. if I execute `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employee;`, is there  possibility to retrieve this?

```
 1) First, we lock a distinct TDUSER."pseudo table" for read on a
 RowHash to prevent global deadlock for TDUSER.employee.
 2) Next, we lock TDUSER.employee for read.
 3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from TDUSER.employee by way of an
 all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 1
 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs. The size of
 Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 2 rows (116 bytes).
 The estimated time for this step is 0.03 seconds.
 4) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
 in processing the request.
 → The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
 statement 1. The total estimated time is 0.03 seconds.
```

I'm using `teradatasql` library now.

Comment: Explain simply returns a result set with a single column. Similar to a Select.

Comment: @dnoeth , thank you, it really does, I was able to retrieve the explain output

Comment: Now you just have to learn how to read them :)

Comment: @Andrew, with dnoeth information, the rest (reading and parsing) is not problem :)